# Will a network congestion occur if I use a single ADSL router connected to 24 port switch

Tags: switch, adsl, congestion

I'm wondering how ADSL networks are implemented in an enterprise.

I have about 20 computers in my network which will be accessing the ADSL internet connection.

This is how my network will be :

ADSL Modem (LAN) ----> (WAN) 24 port switch (LANs) ------------> End users

The ADSL modem's 1 LAN port will be connected to the WAN port of the 24 port switch.
The end users will be connected to the switch via ethernet cables.

Now, I'm wondering since all the traffic converges at the single LAN port of the ADSL modem, will there be a congestion ?

How do large enterprises set up their internet connection in this scenario ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Ethernet connections are full duplex, and in this sense there shouldn't be usually problem on a path from end user to switch, and in most of the time, from switch to ADSL router. However, depending on your end user traffic patterns (applications, time, and so on), the bandwidth available on both upstream and downstream of your ADSL service may be oversubscribed (congested) and if ADSL router can't buffer traffic long enough, drops will occur.

Additionally, most of the ADSL circuits are oversubscribed anyway from ISP point of view, you may not get maximum bandwidth from the link anyway.